# Reuse asynchronous socket: subsequent connect attempts fail

Tags: c#, http, sockets, asynchronous, httpclient

I'm trying to reuse a socket in an asynchronous HTTP client, but I'm not able to connect to the host the second time around. I basically treat my asynchronous HTTP client as a state machine with the following states:

- Available: the socket is available for use
- Connecting: the socket is connecting to the endpoint
- Sending: the socket is sending data to the endpoint
- Receiving: the socket is receiving data from the endpoint
- Failed: there was a socket failure
- Clean Up: cleaning up the socket state

In the connecting state I call `BeginConnect`:

```
private void BeginConnect()
{
    lock (_sync) // re-entrant lock
    {
        IPAddress[] addersses = Dns.GetHostEntry(_asyncTask.Host).AddressList;

        // Connect to any available address
        IAsyncResult result = _reusableSocket.BeginConnect(addersses, _asyncTask.Port, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);
    }
}
```

The callback method changes the state to `Sending` once a successful connection has been established:

```
private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    lock (_sync) // re-entrant lock
    {
        try
        {
            _reusableSocket.EndConnect(result);

            ChangeState(EClientState.Sending);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can't connect to: " + _asyncTask.Host);
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0} Error Code: {1}", e.Message, e.NativeErrorCode);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            {
                // An attempt was made to get the page so perform a callback
                ChangeState(EClientState.Failed);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In the cleanup I `Shutdown` the socket and `Disconnect` with a reuse flag:

```
private void CleanUp()
{
    lock (_sync) // re-entrant lock
    {
        // Perform cleanup 
        if (_reusableSocket.Connected)
        {
            _reusableSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            _reusableSocket.Disconnect(true);
        }
        ChangeState(EClientState.Available);
    }
}
```

Subsequent calls to `BeginConnect` result in a timeout and an exception:

> SocketException: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond XX.XXX.XX.XX:80
>
> Error Code: 10060

Here is the state trace:

```
Initializing...
Change State: Connecting
Change State: Sending
Change State: Receiving
Change State: CleanUp
Callback:     Received data from client 0 // <--- Received the first data 
Change State: Available
Change State: Connecting // <--- Timeout when I try to reuse the socket to connect to a different endpoint
```

What do I have to do to be able to reuse the socket to connect to a different host?

Note: I have <strike>not</strike> tried to re-connect to the same host, but <strike>I assume</strike> the same thing happens (i.e. fails to connect).

**Update**
I found the following note in the [documentation of BeginConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145129.aspx):

> If this socket has previously been disconnected, then BeginConnect must be called on a thread that will not exit until the operation is complete. This is a limitation of the underlying provider. Also the EndPoint that is used must be different.

I'm starting to wonder if my issue has something to do with that... I am connecting to a different EndPoint, but what do they mean that the thread from which we call BeginConnect must not exit until the operation is complete?

**Update 2.0:**
I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764921/whats-the-difference-between-beginconnect-and-connectasync) and I tried using the "Async family" calls instead of the "Begin family" calls, but I get the same problem!!!

Answer (score 2):

I commented on this question: [what is benefit from socket reuse in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133150/what-is-benefit-from-socket-reuse-in-c/4137697#4137697) about socket reuse using `Disconnect(true)/DisconnectEx()` and this may help you.

Personally I think it's an optimisation too far in client code.

Re update 1 to your question; no, you'd get an AbortedOperation exception if that were the case (see here: [VB.NET 3.5 SocketException on deployment but not on development machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609706/vb-net-3-5-socketexception-on-deployment-but-not-on-development-machine/1609915#1609915)) and the docs are wrong if you're running on Vista or later as it doesn't enforce the "thread must exist until after overlapped I/O completes" rule that previous operating systems enforce.

As I've already said in the reply to the linked question; there's very little point in using this functionality for outbound connection establishment. It's likely that it was originally added to the Winsock API to support socket reuse for `AcceptEx()` on inbound connections, where, on a very busy web server that was using `TransmitFile()` to send files to clients (which is where disconnect for reused seems to have originated). The docs state that it doesn't play well with `TIME_WAIT` and so using it for connections where you initiate the active close (and thus put the socket into `TIME_WAIT`, see [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html)) doesn't really make sense.

Can you explain why you think this micro optimisation is actually necessary in your case?

Comment: I don't know why I haven't responded to your question, but the reason I'm doing such micro optimizations is because I'm  fetching 300+ web pages per second and each fetch requires that I close the old socket, dispose of it and open a new one. The application is really long running, so eventually it causes memory thrashing and it slows down the system. Performance is key in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the MaxConnections Setting?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.maxconnections.aspx

Comment: It looks like `NetTcpBinding` is a WCF thing and I'm using raw `Socket`s... I don't see how I can utilize the `NetTcpBinding` with a raw `Socket`.

Comment: ups. i thaught it's the same. i normally put it to the app config like this: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>  
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="32768"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>

Comment: I don't think the sockets are affected by those settings. A lot of socket apps may not even have an app.config, but thanks for your answer anyway :).